# Problem to initiate update for iOS 8

Tags: iphone, software-update, ios

I have a iPhone 5s, and have still not received any information about on-the-air update to iOS 8. So I decide to update manually through iTunes. iTunes gives me an assuring message

> iTunes will update your iPhone to iOS 8.0 and will verify the update with Apple.

and when I click OK, nothing happens. No user interface change, no network usage by iTunes, no error messages, nothing at all. And if I click `Update` button again, the above message shows up again.

Do anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Many others have reported similar problem. The issue is with Apple servers been overloaded. Try at different time (like late night or early morning.

Comment: @Buscar웃: I searched the Internet and had found none reporting the same problem. I almost thought that Apple hates me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your iPhone's Settings. Select `General` -> `Software Update`. Here you can initiate an OTA update. (right now you will be placed in a waiting queue which could range from a few minute to a few hours due to demand).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Rebooting iPhone and MacBook solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.

Make sure you have the latest version of iTunes (which is 11.4).

Now, assuming, you have updated that. The next step is to follow the prompts within iTunes to update. My updates failed repeatedly, but eventually, I came to the conclusion that I could absolutely *not* run anything else associated with the internet. I kept iTunes fully maximized throughout the process and that was all I needed to do! Also, now that it is later in the day, there may be less traffic on Apple's servers :)